# Como substituir uma determinada string dentro de outra string em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

Como posso substituir somente uma determinada parte de uma *string*? Exemplo:

```
var linha_nova = "EU TENHO UM CACHORRO";
```

Quero substituir somente a palavra `"UM"` por outra. Como devo proceder?

Também preciso fazer a substituição pela posição conhecida da palavra a ser substituída. Por exemplo , sei que o "UM" está na décima posição.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você também poderia estar fazendo:

```
var frase = "Eu tenho um cachorro(s)";
var novaFrase = frase.replace(frase.substring(9, 11), "dois");

alert(novaFrase); // Eu tenho dois cachorro(s)
```

Ou utilizando expressões regulares:

```
var frase = "Eu tenho um cachorro(s)";
var novaFrase = frase.replace(/(.{9}).{2}/,"$1dois")

alert(novaFrase); // Eu tenho dois cachorro(s)
```

Answer (score 13):

A forma simples é através da função `replace()` de tipos `string`. [Documentação em inglês](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```js
var linha_nova = "EU TENHO UM CACHORRO";
var linha = linha_nova.replace("UM", "MEDO DE");
console.log(linha);
```

Veja [funcionando no **CodePen**](https://codepen.io/bigown/pen/yMMPWX?editors=1111). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/Replace.js).

Desta forma a variável `linha_nova` permanecerá inalterada e a variável linha conterá "EU TENHO MEDO DE CACHORRO". Se precisar que `linha_nova` seja alterada, você deve guardar o resultado nela e não em `linha`.

Você precisa ter uma certa noção de qual é o conteúdo senão pode ter resultados indesejados. Pode substituir apenas uma parte de uma palavra, por exemplo: "HUMBERTO" pode virar "HMEDO DEBERTO". Pode ter problemas também se tiver a *substring* aparecendo várias vezes.

Mas se quiser resolver situações mais complexas isto pode não ser o mais adequado. A função `replace` permite sintaxe de expressões regulares conforme demostrado na resposta do mgigsonbr.

Se você sabe a posição e o tamanho da parte da *string* que deseja trocar, então use:

```
var linha = linha_nova.substr(0,9) + "MEDO DE" + linha_nova.substr(11, linha_nova.length - 11);
```

Answer (score 10):

#### Substituindo posições específicas

Para substituir apenas uma posição ou intervalo fixo, basta usar `substring`. Primeiro pegue o pedaço do início até a posição inicial que quer substituir, depois o pedaço que começa no final do trecho até o final da string:

```
var linha_nova = "EU TENHO UM CACHORRO";
                //0123456789abcdef
var resultado = linha_nova.substring(0,9) +
                "FOO" +
                linha_nova.substring(11, linha_nova.length);
```

A função `substr` também serve, mas ela recebe não o início e o final desejado, mas sim o início e o número de caracteres desejado.

#### Substituindo palavras específicas

A função `replace` permite substituir uma substring por outra. Ela também permite que você passe uma expressão regular, e para cada casamento (*match*) da mesma, substituí-la por outra string ou pelo resultado de uma função. Se quiser substituir somente a primeira ocorrência, use a chamada com string; se quiser todas, use uma regex com a *flag* `g`:

```
var str = "um cachorro, um gato, um rato";

var uma = str.replace("um", "o"); // o cachorro, um gato, um rato
var alt = str.replace(/um/, "o"); // o cachorro, um gato, um rato

var todas = str.replace(/um/g, "o"); // o cachorro, o gato, o rato

var captura = str.replace(/(um)/g, "xx$1xx"); // xxumxx cachorro, xxumxx gato, xxumxx rato

var funcao = str.replace(/\w+/g, function(match) {
    return Math.random() < 0.5 ? match : match.toUpperCase();
}); // UM cachorro, UM GATO, um rato
```

Note que essa chamada cria uma nova string. Em JavaScript as strings são imutáveis, de modo que não há nenhum meio de se alterar uma string pré-existente sem criar uma nova.

[Exemplos no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/C5yb9/).

Comment: se por exemplo eu quiser substituir por posição ao invés da palavra como seria ? Exemplo, quero substituir uma letra na posição 38. Usaria o substr mesmo ?

Comment: @user7605 Sim, creio que é a melhor maneira. Tipo `str.substring(0,10) + "x" + str.substring(11,str.length)`. Note apenas que `substring` pede o início e o fim, enquanto `substr` pede o início e o número de caracteres.

Answer (score -2):

```
var linha_nova = "EU TENHO UM CACHORRO";
alert(linha_nova.replace("UM", "CARA DE"));
```

Comment: Sou o autor dessa resposta e duas pessoas deram downvote. Fico curioso por que fizeram isso.