# Gostaria de saber se consigo modificar uma string dentro de um array sem saber a sua posição

Tags: javascript, array

Ex:

```
const array=[...'indice n','indice n2',...]
```

Depois de modificar:

```
array = [...'maçã','indice n2,...']
```

---

```
 function checkForTranslation(){
            var input = document.getElementById('inputTextField').value
            var outputDiv = document.getElementById('translationOutputDiv')
            input = input.toLowerCase();
            const newInput = input.split(space)
            var index = newInput.indexOf('hi')
            if(newInput.includes('hi')){
                outputDiv.innerHTML = `${input.replace(/hi/g, '')}`
            }
```

Eu sei que o que está dentro do `if` não faz muito sentido, mas é porque eu não achei uma solução ainda, mas basicamente estou tentando fazer um translate, mas sempre que é escrito a palavra a ser traduzida na frase ela quando substituída pela tradução vai pro final da frase, então pensei transformar a string num array mudar o valor da palavra dentro do array e retornar para string.

Comment: o que tentou e o que está a falhar? Tem de postar algum codigo para que possamos ajudar. Dê uma vista de olhos https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: fiz uma alteração na pergunta, olhe por favor se consegue entender melhor

Comment: vc pode usar um foreach, e procurar o valor e substiuir ele, ou usar  o map
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206125/javascript-es6-es5-find-in-array-and-change/35206193

Comment: Se quer trocar uma palavra de uma string, talvez não precise transformar em array: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16963/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/506410/112052

Comment: Tem que fechar essa pergunta até o autor da mesma a melhorar! O texto é uma pergunta sobre substituir elementos num array, o exemplo apresentado é sobre manipular código HTML. Isso é injusto com autores de respostas pois implica que para quem o responder está sujeito a ser negativado ou por seguir o que está no texto da pergunta e contrariar o código do exemplo ou a ser negativado ou por seguir o que está no código do exemplo e contrariar o texto da pergunta.

Comment: Você interpretou a pergunta totalmente errada então amigo, só apresentei o script que por acaso contem elementos de HTML, mas a pergunta foi 100% focada no array, nada de HTML

Comment: Sua pergunta está confusa e mal elaborada e a função `checkForTranslation()` não apresenta uma interação com array evidente.

Comment: "const newInput = input.split(space) " ele aqui

Comment: Então edite a pergunta e esclareça e junte um [MCVE].

Comment: Pra focar "100% no array", deveria tirar toda a parte "extra" (como o `getElementById` e `innerHTML`, que dependem de um HTML pra testar) e deixar somente o array em si. Aliás, o problema em si é "*como substituir palavras em uma frase*" - o array é apenas a forma como vc tentou, mas não é a única (focar no problema em vez de focar na tentativa de solução pode ser melhor por abrir mais possibilidades de solução: por exemplo, se a frase for "*Oi, tudo bem*" e vc quiser trocar o "Oi", não funcionará porque o `split` irá separar o "Oi," em vez de só o "Oi" - não sei se isso se aplica ao seu caso)

Comment: Não estou muito acostumando em programar, muito menos formular perguntas no stackoverlfow, então eu não sabia que tinha que seguir tantos protocolos, cheguei com uma pergunta e fui recebido com pedra aqui, por mais de uma vez.

Comment: No começo é difícil pegar o jeito mesmo, mas com o tempo vc consegue. Lembre-se que a ideia do site é que as perguntas sejam úteis não só pra vc, mas para qualquer visitante futuro com o mesmo problema. Daí a gente ser meio "chato" e "rígido" com o formato, pois o foco é no problema específico (no seu caso, substituir palavras em uma frase, independente de ter ou não um HTML envolvido), sem "distrações" e "firulas". Dito isso, uma alternativa sem array: https://ideone.com/M4WbmQ

Comment: obrigado amigo, tentei implementar o que voce me mandou mas como vou utilizar outras traduções numa frase por enquanto esta assim: ` var index = newInput.forEach(function cada(item, indice){
                    if(item == 'da'){
                        newInput[indice] = 'good' 
                    }
                    
                    });`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A forma mais coerente seria criar  um prototype, assim vc  pode utilizar a função em verios locais de forma simples.

```
 Array.prototype.replaceAll = function (oldValue, newValue){
         for(var i = 0; i <= this.length;i++){
                      var index = this[i]?.toLowerCase().indexOf(oldValue.toLowerCase());
            if(index == 0){
                    this[i] = this[i].replace(oldValue, newValue)
            } 
        }
       return this;
}

function checkForTranslation(){
     var input ="Morango é uma fruta vermelha assim como a managa é amarela";
     const newInput = input.split(" ")
     var novoValor = newInput.replaceAll("morango", "maça");
     console.log(novoValor)
     console.log(novoValor.join(' '))
}
```

Comment: Ao alterar o protótipo de qualquer objeto, deve-se tomar cuidado com o *prototype pollution*: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/449732/112052

Answer (score -3):

Uma das opções caso você saiba qual valor está buscando dentro desse array é percorrer o array até encontrar o valor desejado e substituir o mesmo.

Função para percorrer o array e alterar o valor desejado.

```
function alter (array, value1, value2) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        if (array[i] === value1) {
          array[i] = value2;
          return;
        }   
    }
return;
}
```

Exemplo de uso da função.

```
let array = ['indice 1', 'indice 2', 'indice 3']
console.log(array); // ["indice 1", "indice 2", "indice 3" ]
alter(array, 'indice 2', 'maça');
console.log(array) // [ "indice 1", "maça", "indice 3" ]
```

Answer (score -3):

```
function checkForTranslation(){
            var input = document.getElementById('inputTextField').value
            var outputDiv = document.getElementById('translationOutputDiv')
            input = input.toLowerCase();
            const space = ' ';
            const newInput = input.split(space)
            if (newInput.indexOf('hi') >= 0) {
            var index = newInput.indexOf('hi')
            newInput[index] = 'oi'
            console.log(newInput)
            const finalInput = newInput.join(' ');
            outputDiv.innerHTML = finalInput
            }
```

Não sei se dei volta demais mas no final das contas funcionou certinho, valeu galera

Comment: Tem um porém: se a palavra ocorre mais de uma vez na frase, você só substitui a primeira ocorrência

Comment: é acabei de descobri esse problema ae, to tentando resolver

Comment: Então melhore a pergunta, pois se reaberta eu garanto que a sua pergunta tem o potencial de receber respostas de qualidade muito acima das que vem recebendo. Apresente um [mcve] onde qualquer um o possa testar, defina os parâmetros e limites de substituição, concentre-se no array pense no seu problema de forma mais genérica onde que qualquer um no futuro que tiver problema similar ao seu possa recorrer a sua pergunta e as respostas a sua pergunta em busca de solução fazendo o mínimo de modificações possiveis.