# como trocar vogais de uma string por números?

Tags: javascript

```js
**>function trocaVogais(string){
  palavra="paralelepipedo";
   const arr = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < palavra.length; i++) {
    if(palavra[i]=="aeiou"){
palavra=arr.push(1);
}
   return palavra;
}
    trocaVogais();**


//Não sei como resolver, pode ser que esteja meio errado(ou completamente) ali em cima, alguém pode corrigir?

//Exemplo: se for passada a palavra “uva”, a função deve retornar “1v1”


//Exemplo: se for passada a palavra “carro”, a função deve retornar “c1rr1”
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: [Como substituir uma determinada string dentro de outra string em Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16963/como-substituir-uma-determinada-string-dentro-de-outra-string-em-javascript?rq=1)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```js
const str = 'carro';
console.log(str.replace(/a|e|i|o|u/g, 1));
```